Butterworth Bandpass Filter Design
Determine the transfer function for the Butterworth bandpass filter? (At the Transfer Function Factoring and Sp Substitution stage)
The Parameter
$$a_{pass} = - 1dB$$
$$a_{stop} = - 20dB$$
$$f_{pass1} = 10kHz$$
$$f_{pass2} = 30kHz$$
$$f_{stop1} = 5kHz$$
$$f_{stop2} = 60kHz$$
A. Approximate Low Pass Filter

Filter Ordo
$$n_B = 4.29$$
$$n_B = 5 $$

Magnitude Response
$$\epsilon = 0.51$$

Radius
$$R = 1,144$$

Angles
$$m = 1$$



While m = 0
$$\theta_0 = 108°$$

While m = 1
$$\theta_1 = 144°$$



Find $$\sigma_m$$ Value and $$\omega_m$$ value


While m = 0

$$\sigma_0 = -0.354 $$
$$\omega_0 = 1.089 $$

While m = 1

$$\sigma_1 = -0.926 $$
$$\omega_1 = 0.673 $$
$$\sigma R = - 1.144$$

Find Value B1m and B2m

$$B_{1,0} = 0.708$$
$$B_{1,1} = 1.852 $$
$$B_{2,0} = 1.311 $$
$$B_{2,1} = 1.310 $$

Low Pass Filter Aproximation Transfer Function

$$H_{B,5}(S) = \frac{1.144}{S} \frac{(1.311)(1.310)}{(S^2 + 0.708S + 1.311)(S^2 +  1.852 + 1.310)}$$
B. Unnormalized Butterworth Band Pass Filter

$$ \Omega_{rP} $$

$$ \Omega_{rP} = 2.75$$

$$ \omega_0 $$

$$ \omega_0 = 108.827,96 rad/s$$

$$BW$$

$$BW = 125.663,71 rad/s$$

$$Sp = \frac{s^2+108.827,96}{125.663,71s}$$

Factoring Transfer Function and Subtitute S.


I'm still confused about the step of factoring the transfer function and substituting specific values to determine the transfer function of a Butterworth bandpass filter. Can someone help me?

Verbatim cross-post of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708811/determine-the-transfer-function-for-the-butterworth-bandpass-filter-at-the-tra
